# SQL DYNAMIC PIVOT - WITH CONDITIONS

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following query that returns a car reg number together with the date it was seen and the camera that saw it:

```
SELECT PLATE_READ.RegNumber, PLATE_READ.DateSeen, PLATE_READ.CameraId FROM PLATE_READ

REG         DATESEEN               CAMERAID
===         ========               ========
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:10:57    2
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:05:03    1
G2412       02/07/2014 13:22:01    1
G2412       02/07/2014 13:24:05    2
G6981V      02/07/2014 14:25:08    1
```

I would like to be able to query and have 1 row returned per registration number stating the dates it has been seen per camera with the following format:

```
REG         1                    2        
===         ===================  ===================
G2412       02/07/2014 13:22:01  02/07/2014 13:24:05   
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:05:03  20/12/2013 12:10:57
```

The result should be ordered by descending date where cameraid is 1. And the dateseen of cameraid 1 must be less than cameraid 2.

Note that the same plate could have been seen by camera 1 and camera 2 many times, however the last entries must be used only for both.

I have tried several threads but no luck.

Comment: I am assuming that the record for reg `G6981V` not included because to show in the results a reg must have been seen by both cameras?

Comment: thats correct Gareth. Seen by both and the date record on camera 1 must be less than camera 2.

Comment: What DB do you use (SQLServer,...)?

Comment: it seems to me that you aren't going to have more than 2 cameras in your explanation. is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the criteria is:

- Reg must have been seen by both cameras
- Camera 2 time must be after camera 1 time.

I am also assuming based on previous questions you are using SQL Server.

The way I would approach this may slightly counter intuitive, but I would find the latest sighting by camera 2 for each reg, then find the sighting by camera to 1 prior to that:

```
SELECT  C2.Reg, C1.[1], C2.[2]
FROM    (   SELECT  Reg, [2] = MAX(DateSeen)
            FROM    T
            WHERE   CameraID = 2
            GROUP BY T.Reg
        ) AS C2
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 [1] = DateSeen
            FROM    T
            WHERE   T.Reg = C2.Reg
            AND     T.DateSeen < C2.[2]
            ORDER BY T.DateSeen DESC
        ) AS C1
ORDER BY C1.[1] DESC;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7179/6)**

Although I have potentially over complicated this, this will still show a vehicle if it was seen by camera 1 last, but display the time it was seen by camera 1 previously, i.e. with this data

```
REG         DATESEEN               CAMERAID
===         ========               ========
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:15:03    1
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:10:57    2
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:05:03    1
```

the result would be:

```
REG         1                       2
===         ========               ========
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:05:03     20/12/2013 12:10:57
```

So ignoring the latest row for camera 1 because it was not seen by camera 2 after. If you want to just completely remove this vehicle from the results then you can use a much simpler PIVOT query:

```
SELECT  pvt.Reg, pvt.[1], pvt.[2]
FROM    T
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(DateSeen)
            FOR CameraID IN ([1], [2])
        ) AS pvt
WHERE   pvt.[2] > pvt.[1]
ORDER BY pvt.[1] DESC;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7179/7)**

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right you need the last (MAXIMUM) time for both 1 and 2 cameras:

```
    SELECT 
         REG,
         MAX(CASE WHEN CameraID=1 THEN DATESEEN END) as [c1],
         MAX(CASE WHEN CameraID=2 THEN DATESEEN END) as [c2]
    FROM PLATE_READ
    GROUP BY REG
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN CameraID=1 THEN DATESEEN END)
           <
           MAX(CASE WHEN CameraID=2 THEN DATESEEN END)
   ORDER BY [c1] DESC
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47727/6)</kbd>